# How do I disable a connection in a server when the Internet connection is lost

Tags: router, lan, ping, network-access

We are using a router to connect multiple devices. We have a server connected to the Internet that will continually ping a website to check if there is still an Internet connection. If there is no Internet connection, we will cut the connection of those devices connected to the server as a precaution since our system requires an Internet connection to work. The computers connected to the server will constantly ping it, and if the connection is cut will run a program to stop anything from happening.

Our first idea was to release the IP address in the server on the LAN interface if there is no internet connection, and then renew it when the connection returns. This will terminate the connection between the server and other computers, but our server's LAN IP address is statically assigned for added security measures, and it cannot be released and renewed.

Another option for us is to disable the LAN interface on the server so that the other computers cannot ping it, but we are looking for a better solution, or is this the best solution for our problem?

Comment: What kind of router/switch do you have?

Comment: so you simply need the users to not access the server when the internet is down ????

Comment: @Gadeliow yes! we decided to have 2 networks in the server one for the internet and the other for the users, and if the internet is down it will just be disabled the network for the users and enable them when the internet is back

Comment: @RonTrunk belkin or cisco wrt100 router

Comment: This is something that is best handled inside the server application. The application should inform users that the Internet connection is not available and refuse to process for the users until it is available. Another option, depending on how critical the application is, is to have redundant Internet connections.

Comment: @RonMaupin that is actually an option, but this is for the worst of the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you refer to topology like this:

[image]

If you need to disable user access to the server when the Internet is down, you may create patch file to change the IP address of the network card with the ***NETSH*** command. *Make use of this link [NETSH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)*, and create aother patch to restore the original IP address when the Internet connection is restored.

Using some routers, it may accomplished using IP SLA which is not supported by your router model.

Comment: that is actually not a bad idea, thanks for that!  we might just use this instead of creating 2 networks in the server.

Comment: yes try it first to change the ip and then create to patches one to change the ip and other to restore it back . some cmd commands would be useful to automate such process but i'm not a ware of them at all . but you may think in ping the internet and if it came down then run the first patch and if it cams bake run the second patch

Comment: Yes we just did it now and it worked, will just use a batch file to run this. thank you.